# Add Thread to a List with Option Strict

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I wrote this code:

```
Dim TL As New List(Of Thread)
For x = 0 To 10
    TL.Add(New Thread(AddressOf ThreadWork))
    TL(x).Start(x)
Next
```

It works fine with `Option Strict Off`.
But if I turn `Option Strict On` I get error (overload resolution failed) on `TL.Add(New Thread(AddressOf ThreadWork))`

I also tried

```
Dim T As New Thread(AddressOf ThreadWork)
TL.Add(T)
```

but still get error.

I searched the web and I found the same syntax on msdn ([here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/315577)), so I don't understand where I'm wrong.

ThreadWork is: `Private Sub ThreadWork(ByVal W As Integer)`

**My goal is to get some threads into a List or into an Array** so any hint on this way is apprecciated

Comment: can you show how `TL` is defined/declared

Comment: Strictly, the ThreadWork argument must be Object, not Integer.  Consider using a lambda expression to keep it type-safe.

Comment: @Plutonix Sorry, addedd TL declaration

Comment: @HansPassant I'm testing this logic to see if it can work for what I want to write: ThreadWork will be a complex sub

Comment: What version of .net are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Dim TL As New List(Of Thread)
Dim T As New Thread(Sub(w As Object)
                        ThreadWork(CInt(w))
                    End Sub)
TL.Add(T)
```

Your method:

```
Private Sub ThreadWork(ByVal W As Integer)

End Sub
```

Comment: Please google "capture for loop variable is harmful" to learn why your answer will get the OP in trouble.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
For x = 0 To 10
    TL.Add(New Thread(Sub(param As Object) ThreadWork(CType(param, Integer))))
    TL(x).Start(x)
Next
```

It creates a lambda expression with the same signature as a [**`ParameterizedThreadStart`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate (like Hans said the parameter must be of type `Object`). When executed the lambda method will call your `ThreadWork` method and attempt to convert the parameter to an `Integer`.

If you're targeting **.NET 3.5 or lower** you can use this solution instead:

```
For x = 0 To 10
    TL.Add(New Thread(AddressOf ThreadWorkStub))
    TL(x).Start(x)
Next
```

The `ThreadWorkStub` method:

```
Private Sub ThreadWorkStub(ByVal param As Object)
    ThreadWork(CType(param, Integer))
End Sub
```

Comment: You are not capturing x so the copy is not necessary.

Comment: I accepted Giovanni Russo's answer because he was faster but +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
Dim TL As New List(Of Thread)
For x As Integer = 0 To 10
    Dim thrd As New Thread(AddressOf ThreadWork)
    TL.Add(thrd)
    thrd.Start(x)
Next
```

'
'

```
Private Sub ThreadWork(someInt As Object)
    Dim i As Integer = DirectCast(someInt, Integer)
    Debug.WriteLine(i)
    'other code
End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot to pass the parameter.

Comment: @genespos - corrected to add parameter, and tested.